# Relaciones entre Clases

Tags: base-de-datos, uml, diseño-de-clases

Estoy trabajando en Diagrama de Clases y mi pegunta es si, una *Clase X* puede tener 2 relaciones con una *Clase Y*.

*Me explico*: Clase X puede tener herencia y dependencia con Clase Y?

[image]

Es a lo que me refiero, puede existir esto entre dos clases?

Gracias por la atención, la colaboración y la paciencia

Comment: una clase puede tener varias clases heredadas se conoce como [Herencia multiple](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herencia_m%C3%BAltiple)pero te puede dar el [problema del diamante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante), la solucion de algunos Lenguajes es no colocarla, Java directamente no existe pero muchos lo manejan por extends e implements

Comment: exactamente ahora tengo el problema del diamante, bien? 

pero me sirve lo de Herencia Múltiple...

Por eso pregunto si puedo darle la relación de dependencia...

Comment: No hablemos de código, solo concentrémonos en Diagrama de Clases. La pregunta es sencilla. Una clase puede tener relación de herencia y dependencia al mismo tiempo con otra clase? Me hice explicar el contexto?

Comment: entiendo lo que me decís. Edité la pregunta un poco para más claridad. Una disculpa si no me hago entender.

Comment: tu respuesta es si se puede, pero, para que vas a heredar si vas a reescribir los metodos?

Comment: entiendo a que te refieres... y ya resolví esa cuestión. Gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, resolví muchas más cosas.

Comment: entonces te invito a agregar tu respuesta explicarla y un  dia despues cerrar la pregunta como validad, y tambien eliminar los comentarios innecesarios

Answer (score 0):

A ver si he entendido bien tu pregunta. Paso a contestarte:

Puedes heredar de una clase X y a su vez tener atributos de dicha clase X. Un ejemplo (escrito en Java y C++) sería el siguiente:

Ejemplo en Java:

```
public class X{
[...]
}

public class Y extends X{
private X x;
[...]
}
```

Ejemplo en C++:

```
class X{
[...]
};
class Y: public X{
private:
  X x;
[...]
}
```

Comment: Gracias, entonces es afirmativo.? Porque solo entendí el punto de herencia. Incluye la herencia, la dependencia?

Comment: Creo que la pregunta hace referencia a diseño de base de datos, no a programacion, puede ser?..

Comment: está en lo correcto